# Let m be a positive integer and $p=16m+7$. Show that if $p$ is a prime, then $2^{8m+3}-1$ is composite

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can I show that? I know it has to do with a lemma but I couldn't find the one.

Comment: Are you quite sure that what you're trying to prove is true to begin with?

Comment: Totally my bad, fixing it right now. Sorry!

Comment: Hint: show that $p$ divides $2^{8m+3}-1$ using Euler's criterion.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get on that! @GregMartin

Comment: I couldn't do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Greg Martin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16078/greg-martin) suggested, according to [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), $\left(\dfrac2p\right)\equiv2^{(p-1)/2}\pmod p.$

Furthermore, if $p=16m+7$, then $p\equiv-1\pmod8$, so $\left(\dfrac2p\right)=1$.

Thus, $p$ is a factor of $2^{(p-1)/2}-1$.

For positive integers $m$, $16m+7\lt 2^{8m+3}-1$, so this means $2^{(p-1)/2}-1$ is composite.

Comment: Can't we just say if $p$ is a factor of $2^{(p-1)/2}-1$ then $p|2^{(p-1)/2}-1$?

Comment: Thanks btw, helped a lot!!

Comment: that's true, but note that, for $m=0$, $p=2^{(p-1)/2}-1$ is prime

Comment: Alright! But the question says let $m$ be a positive integer so think that should do. Thanks again!

Comment: right; I was merely pointing out in my last comment that $p|2^{(p-1)/2}-1$ doesn't necessarily mean $2^{(p-1)/2}-1$ is composite, and that's why I also indicated in my answer that $p<2^{(p-1)/2}-1$